# Regex error in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a collection which contains documents like :

```
> db.people.find().limit(1).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5......e"),
    "name" : "Potter, Harry",
    "pos" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5....9"),
            "rtype" : "executive"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following queries ended up with errors:

```
> db.people.find( { name : /.*Harry.*/i })
error: { "$err" : "invalid regular expression operator", "code" : 13454 }
> 
> db.people.find( { name : /Harry/i })
error: { "$err" : "invalid regular expression operator", "code" : 13454 }
> 
> db.people.find({"name" : {$regex : "/.*Harry.*/i"} })
error: { "$err" : "invalid regular expression operator", "code" : 13454 }
```

Googling gave [no good result](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md) for this error code 13454. According to the [official doc for regex in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex), it should work!

Eventually I need to run such queries on a MEAN stack.
So, how do I match regexes for that? I cannot figure out any problem with my queries!

**Update:**

- MongoDB: version v2.2.4, pdfile version 4.5
- OS: ubuntu 13.04

if that matters

**Update 2 :**

As @Parvin pointed out, these queries are correct. **MY** MongoDB version was faulty. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using? 1st & 2nd queries should work. For the 3rd one you have to update query as db.people.find({"name" : {$regex : ".*Harry.*", $options : "i"} })

Comment: @parvin : `mongodb version v2.2.4, pdfile version 4.5`. Yes, 1st and 2nd should work, ideally, and are driving me nuts! in 3rd one, `$option : "i"` is optional and used for case insensitivity.

Comment: @parvin : Thanks! Version was the problem. Seems like v2.2.x has some problem running regexes. Reinstalling with v2.4 fixes it.

Comment: I tried your example regex queries in 2.2.4 and couldn't reproduce the error messages.  The problem must have been in your installation of MongoDB 2.2.4 (i.e. not related to 2.2.x running the regexes). Also FYI, you don't need to include the ".*" before and after the word you are searching for; this is implicit unless you have anchored the match at the beginning (`^`) or end (`S`) of a string.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Stennie. I have edited my question to emphasis on *my* version, just in case somebody gets the same error. And regex searching point noted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who get into this problem, it seems from Stennie's comment in the question, that  **my installation of version 2.2.4 was faulty**. Ubuntu, by default, installs v2.2.x even if your repository is updated. In order to use newest version and avoid silly bugs, follow the steps below.

Instead of doing:

**<strike>sudo apt-get install mongodb-server</strike>**

To remove existing mongodb-server package, use purge option:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-server
```

Then follow the commands given at [MongoDB Site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to install `mongodb-10gen`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `regex` operator.

```
db.people.find( { name : { "$regex" : "/*Harry/*" , "$options" : "i"} })
```

Comment: it gave the same error: `error: { "$err" : "invalid regular expression operator", "code" : 13454 }`